# Why is my google map api not displaying balloons properly?

Tags: css, google-maps

Here's the link: [www.mchenry.edu/maps/google.asp](http://www.mchenry.edu/maps/google.asp)

Why won't the location balloon display correctly? Also, the pop-up info box is wonky too. Is it something in the CSS? Finally, I've received not a few "google server rejects your api key" yada yada. I've changed the key twice, with little luck. Hopefully it will work for you.

Thanks for any info you may have! Be nice to this noob. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following entry in your "records.css" file is causing the problem:

```
img {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```